# table design to track significant events associated with an item

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-design, best-practices

An `Orders` table I'm dealing with at present in design phase has about 10 or more columns.

Each `OrderID` in the `Orders` table will have certain **significant events** or **milestones**. The number of `Orders` could go into the millions. At the moment, I'm aware of about **20** important events to track for each `Order`, but that number may increase or decrease.

Of these 20 or so events, only a handful will always take place, while the rest are just potential events. Also, many - but not all - of these events have at least two points which need storage:

1. the Date the event is *supposed* to happen (if it is no longer just a "potential" event)
2. the Date the event *did* happen

The events data will be updated in the database from external sources in the form of `.xls` or `.csv` files. For all events, it is only possible for the given event to happen **once**.

What would be the best design for storing this milestone event data?
Would you try to use a somewhat normalized design, where there is an `Events` table designed similar to this...

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Events (
    EventID             INT
    , OrderID           INT
    , EventExpectedDate DATEIME2(7)
    , EventActualDate   DATETIME2(7)
    , EventTypeID       INT
    , EventSkip         BIT
    ...
    )
```

Or would you try a less normalized approach and flatten all the possible events out into one  **very wide** events table that mimics what the `.xls/.csv` update files will look like?

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Events (
    EventID             INT
    , OrderID           INT
    , Event_1_ExpDate   DATEIME2(7)  /* No, the actual names would not include 1, 2, 3 */
    , Event_1_ActDate   DATETIME2(7) /* The actual names would name type of Event */
    , Event_2_ExpDate   DATETIME2(7)
    , Event_2_ActDate   DATETIME2(7)
    ...
    , Event_20_ExpDate   DATETIME2(7)
    , Event_20_ActDate   DATETIME2(7)
    )
```

Or is there another pattern you would use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normalize always unless you have a very good reason not to. It should not be flipping a coin.

Neither of your proposed designs seems optimal to me for a variable / unknown number of events, since when "that number may increase or decrease," in both cases, you have to change the schema *and* the code.

I also don't believe that you have to base your core table design around the format of the input files. This is why we have staging tables, ETL processes, SSIS, C#, etc. There are many ways to transform data from flat files into a format that is more appropriate for a relational database. Don't design your database because of what your flat files look like.

So you could have *staging* tables that look like the input files, but then you would load the data into *real* tables that look perhaps like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Events -- lookup table describing events
(
  EventID INT PRIMARY KEY,
  Description VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.OrderEventLog -- actual event data
(
  EventID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Events(EventID),
  OrderID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Orders(OrderID), -- guess
  ExpectedDate DATETIME2(7),
  ActualDate DATETIME2(7)
);
```

Now when you have a new type of event, you just insert it into the `dbo.Events` table, and then you can insert related events into `dbo.OrderEventLog` without having to change the schema of either table, and without having to change the interface to your stored procedures or bulk inserts into the staging tables either. This also keeps the history table (and all of its indexes) nice and narrow, and allows you to build indexes that favor searches for specific types of events.

You can always flatten the data later - which is typically what you do when you get to a point where you are building a data warehouse around the data.

Comment: Thanks. I guess one of my concerns is the process for `.xls/.csv` updates will be more complicated with the table being normalized. Do you have an example of what *would* constitute "...a very good reason not to" normalize?

Comment: @mg1075 typically you want to denormalize when you're done writing to the table and it is going to be used primarily or solely for reporting.

Comment: Yep, thanks for the reminder. Still curious, though, if you know of the edge cases where it would be good *not* to normalize up front?

Comment: @mg1075 off the top of my head, I can't really think of any specific use cases except in general when the data structure is fixed and permanent and it is a very dumb data store. Are you looking for a solution to a problem you don't actually have?

Comment: In the old days you'd do a fair amount of de-normalisation for performance reasons. Not so much now, and certainly not with your model

Comment: @AaronBertrand - just looking for clarity. Since you went through the trouble of specifying primary and foreign keys in your examples, is there a reason you did not make the EventID and OrderID a clustered primary key? Sorry if I'm being a pain - I do appreciate your guidance.

Comment: @mg1075 because I have no idea if that is a primary key. Can an order only have a certain event once? That's not a question I can answer and I didn't feel like making any more assumptions.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - yes, in this case, each event can only happen once for an order. I failed to make that clear in the original post.