# Many-to-many tables tracking participation at multiple events

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am working on a side project to track observations of different birds, and the time spent during each observation. Right now I have a table called `Observations`:

```
 obs_id   |   start_time  | end_time  |   date      |  location
--------------------------------------------------------------------
    1            3            36         27/09/2016    acadia park
    2            4            00         27/09/2016    zion park
    3            12           50         27/09/2016    acadia park
    4            16           32         27/09/2016    yellowstone
    5            9            20         28/09/2016    zion park
    6            21           50         28/09/2016    yellowstone
```

However, multiple people are observing these birds, and I would like to be able to query the people associated with these birds. I would also like to keep a running total of each person's observation time.

So I have a table of `Observers`, with a column for their total time spent observing (in hours, calculated from the `start_time` and `end_time` columns in the `Observations` table), but I'm not sure of the best way to relate these two tables. I want to relate these two tables so that I can see the observations that each person was involved with.

```
 person_id   |   total_time  | name  
-----------------------------------------
    1            1.5          Jane Doe        
    2            4            John Doe      
    3            5            James Doe         
    4            6            Jenny Doe        
    5            3            Jeremy Doe
```

Unfortunately, there can be multiple people at an observation, and the same person can have multiple observations, too. That makes this (if I understand correctly) a many-to-many relationship. I'm wondering how to go about fixing that. Should I make a separate associative entity? Or should I just add a column into `Observations` that contains a foreign key for `Observers`, and create new rows for each observer – something like this?

```
 obs_id   |   person_id  | start_time  |  end_time |   date      |  location
--------------------------------------------------------------------
    1           1_1            3          36          27/09/2016    acadia park
    1           1_2            3          36          27/09/2016    acadia park
    2           2_1            4          00          27/09/2016    zion park
    2           2_2            4          00          27/09/2016    zion park
    2           2_3            4          00          27/09/2016    zion park
    2           2_4            4          00          27/09/2016    zion park
    3           3_1            12         50          28/09/2016    yellowstone
```

This will be implemented using PHP, allowing users to submit their observations on a website and updating a SQL database (MySQL). I've looked at some other problems, like [tracking events associated with an item](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36320/table-design-to-track-significant-events-associated-with-an-item), or [tracking student attendance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52006/database-design-to-track-student-attendance), but none of them have quite the same problem that I do.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, your system could comprise:

- a `Locations` table with location information and a `location_id`

  a `People` or `Observers` table with personal details and a `person_id`

  an `Observations` table just the way you have it

  and an `Observer_Observations` table with `person_id` and `obs_id`

(i.e. your many-to-many table)

The `total_time` column in your `Observers` table should be calculated from `Observer_Observations` rather than stored.

Comment: Thanks for the response! But how would total_time be calculated from Observer_Observations? Wouldn't it be calculated from the start_time and end_time columns in Observers?

Comment: @Alice you mean Observations? Yes, you have to join Observations and Observer_Observations (and maybe Observers as well) to output a calculated total time.